# How to avoid passing "redundant" arguments in function?

Tags: c, function, parameters, arguments

I was writing some code and I realised that I kept on passing arguments to functions when the function didn't use the argument. Only the sub-function with the function( or the sub-sub-function within the sub-function and so on...)   used it.

The actual function never used the arguments at all, it's only purpose was to "relay" the arguments to the sub-function(or the sub-sub-function and so on)

Eg:

```
int search(int (*board)[DIM],int search_digit,int * bestRow,int *bestCol)
{ 
  //some code,haven't use arguments bestRow,bestCol

  longest=seq_length( board,longest,search_digit,bestRow,bestCol,r,c); //sub-function

  //some code,haven't use arguments bestRow,bestCol
}
```

---

```
int seq_length(int board[][DIM],int longest,int search_digit,int * bestRow,int *bestCol,int row,int col)
{
  //some code,haven't use arguments bestRow,bestCol

  longest=updateLongest_best(bestRow,bestCol,longest,seqLength,row,col); //sub-sub-function

  //some code,haven't use arguments bestRow,bestCol

}
```

---

```
int updateLongest_best(int* bestRow,int *bestCol,int longest,int seqLength,int row,int col)
{ 
 //finally used arguments bestRow,bestCol
}
```

Is there an elegant way to circumvent the passing of redunant arguments? Or is this just inherent part of C?

Comment: I would say that you need to refactor the code to flatten the call tree, but without [real code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's hard to say.

Comment: I would say that if a parameter needs to be passed to a subfunction... it is not redundant! Now, `bestRow` and `bestCol` are pointers returned by `search()`. The real question is: does the caller of `search()` use or set) those parameters? If yes you are done.

Comment: The 'obvious' alternative is to 'pass' those variables via a global variable.  This is ***not*** (that is, ***NOT***) a good idea — the code as written is better.  If you have two or more such arguments (as here), you could consider combining them into a structure that is passed by pointer so there's only one direct argument.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Are you saying that as long as the caller of search() uses those parameters mentioned, it's not redundant

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I could have used structs here, thank you!

Comment: @user3386109 I'm kind of a newbie so I have no idea on refactoring

Comment: `typedef struct { int x, y; } vec2i; int updateLongest_best(vec2i *bestCell, int longest, int seqLength, vec2i cell)) {...}`

Comment: @Leon That's what [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is for. They will be happy to show you how to refactor the code. But they do require real working code.

Comment: @user3386109 I'll try that then.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler would it be possible for you to convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @Leon — like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61994125/15168)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Converting my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61981423/how-to-avoid-passing-redundant-arguments-in-function?noredirect=1#comment109624525_61981423) into an answer.*</sup>

The 'obvious' alternative is to 'pass' those variables via a global variable. This is ***not*** (repeat, ***NOT***) a good idea — the code as written is better.

If you have two or more arguments that are relayed from one function to another (as here), you could consider combining them into a structure that is passed by pointer so there's only one direct argument to each called function.

Note that if the functions that are called from a sub-function need the information passed to the calling function by the user, then the arguments are not 'redundant'; they're necessary, even if verbose.

In outline:

```
typedef struct BestInfo
{
    int row;
    int col;
} BestInfo;

int search(int (*board)[DIM], int search_digit, BestInfo *best)
{ 
    // some code; doesn't use argument best

    longest=seq_length(board, longest, search_digit, best,  r, c); //sub-function

    // some more code; doesn't use argument best
}

int seq_length(int board[][DIM], int longest, int search_digit, BestInfo *best, int row, int col)
{
    // code that doesn't use argument best

    longest = updateLongest_best(best, longest, seqLength, row, col); //sub-sub-function

    // more code that doesn't use argument best
    return …;
}

int updateLongest_best(BestInfo *best, int longest, int seqLength, int row, int col)
{ 
    // Finally use argument best: best->row, best->col
    // You can split the structure when appropriate
    int r1 = one_more_function(&best->row);
    int r2 = another_function(&best->col);
    return computation_using(r1, r2);
}
```